# How can I fix a string that creates some random characters?

Tags: c, reverse, c-strings, fgets

The problem is that when I try to reverse a word, there are some words that prints out with unspecified and random characters. I tried to change the string size and the results change (some words make up random characters and some no)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN 20

void reverse( char w[LEN]);

int main() {
char word[LEN];

reverse(word);

return 0;
}

void reverse (char w[LEN]){

char rev[LEN];
int i,j;
fgets(w, LEN, stdin);

for (i = 0, j = strlen(w)-1; i < strlen(w); i++, j--){
    rev[j] = w[i]; 
}

printf("%s\n", rev);

return;

}
```

An example of my problem is this:

Input: `bathroom`

Output: `moorhtabp⬧⬧oz⬧`

Every time I execute the program, with the same input the output changes.

Comment: `fgets()` will add `\n` at the end of the string

Comment: @reshi You forgot to append the array rev with the zero-terminating character '\0'.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add a `'\0'` or `0` at the end of `rev` to terminate it.

```
for (i = 0, j = strlen(w)-1; i < strlen(w); i++, j--)
{
    rev[j] = w[i]; 
}
rev[i] = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few errors:

1. `fgets()` add an newline `\n` at the end of the string.
2. You must add a string terminator (0 byte) after the last character.
3. (Lesser issue) Using `strlen()` in the loop condition will iterate over the string multiple times. It usually results in O(N^2) algorithms.

Fixes:

1. Variant A

Use `scanf` to parse a single word
`scanf(" %19s", w)`
The specifier `%19s` scans up to 19 characters and add NULL terminator to fix 20-char-long array

1. Variant B

Check if the last character of `w` is `\n`. If so, replace it with zero.

```
int L = strlen(w);
if (L > 0 && w[L - 1] == '\n') {
  w[--L] = 0;
}
```

2. Just put

```
rev[i] = 0;
```

at the end.

3. Just iterate until j is negative, meaning it reached the "one before first" character and there is nothing more to do.

```
for (i = 0, j = L-1; j >= 0; i++, j--)
    rev[j] = w[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters the call of the function

```
char word[LEN];

reverse(word);
```

does not make a sense because neither string is passed to the function. You passed an uninitialized character array.

The function should do only one thing: reverse the passed string.
So the call of `fgets` should be removed from the function and placed in main.

The function `fgets` can append the new line character `'\n'` to the entered string.  You need to remove it.

Within the function `reverse` you forgot to append the terminating zero character `'\0'` to the reversed string. So this call

```
printf("%s\n", rev);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Also the type of the returned value of the standard C function `strlen` is the unsigned integer type `size_t`. You should use this type instaed of the signed integer type `int`.

And this declaration of the function

```
void reverse( char w[LEN])
```

also does not make a great sense because the compiler will adjust it to the following declaration

```
void reverse( char *w)
```

and in general the user can pass to the function a string of any length that can be greater than the value `LEN`.

Below there is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be written.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * reverse( char *s )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0, n = strlen( s ); i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n - i - 1];
        s[n - i - 1] = c;
    }
    
    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 20 };
    char s[N];
    
    fgets( s, N, stdin );
    
    s[ strcspn( s, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
    
    puts( s );
    puts( reverse( s ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

If to enter string `"Hello World!"` then the program output will be

```
Hello World!
!dlroW olleH
```